# I have an issue about getting the response from displayalert message in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, logic

I need to get the return value from a displayAlert pop-up. But it's a lil bit complicated because I put this pop-up into an if statement, it's not in an async void method. Here is the code:

```
private void cityButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (cityButton.Text == "Amsterdam")
   {
       DisplayAlert("Congrats!", "You Did it", "Exit", "Save");
   }
}
```

What I wanna do is, getting the answer, and create an if statement right after that displayAlert which would be something like that:

```
if(answer == "Save")
{
 do something
}
else //this is gonna be for the exit part
{
do something
}
```

But I cannot take the value out because the displayAlert pop-up is not in an async void method. And I cannot use an async method in that if statement. Can anybody help me with that issue?

Comment: I haven't use xamarin but document may help you?
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups)
The "OnActionSheetSimpleClicked " function seems similar and will get bool 'answer'

Comment: yeah, I've already checked that out before posting here, but the pop-up is in an "async void" method there. mine is a lil bit different than the examples given in there. there is not an async method in my version. But thank you so much for the recommendation ;)

Comment: @phoenix , what's stopping you to assign the method as async?

Comment: @phoenix , what's stopping you to assign the method as async?

Comment: @Александр  async private void cityButton_Clicked   <<  like this?

Comment: @高鵬翔 , yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Hey guys, you are hilarious!!! It looks the code works like that! I didn't think that any button which has another function than throwing a displayalert can get async method! You Александр and 高鵬翔 both saved me! Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ContinueWith` instead `async/await` like this:

```
private void cityButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (cityButton.Text == "Amsterdam")       
    {  
        DisplayAlert("Congrats!", "You Did it", "Exit", "Save").ContinueWith(tsk => {

          if(tsk.Result == true) { 
            // do something 
          } 
          else //this is gonna be for the exit part 
          { 
            // do something 
          }

        }); 
    }
}
```

But I don't see some reason why you can't use `async/await` for this function assignment

Comment: I didn't think to use the async method with that button :) I thought that cannot be :) but thanx, I will check this out, too!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use this return valve of `DisplayAlert`, if you click the `Yes`, you will get the `True` value, if you click the `No`, you will get the `false` value

```
  private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var answer = await DisplayAlert("Question?", "Would you like to play a game", "Yes", "No");
            Debug.WriteLine("Answer: " + answer); // writes true or false to the console
        }
```